# "Connection refused" when xamarin.android is trying to contact WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i'm pretty new to *xamarin* and i'm *trying to use this techno with a web service*.

At the moment I just have a *login page* that asks my web service if a user can login.
To achieve this, my login button *uses a portable class that calls the web service*.

*I hosted the web service on a web server (IIS)*.
*So I use a remote ip to use my webservice*

**I have been looking for solutions for several hours, the problem remains the same.**

If someone can help me it would be nice, remember to tell me if you need more information!

**Facts :** 
-The connection returns the correct result when I use wcftestclient.exe
-The connection returns me the good result when I use UWP
**-When I use my android phone in debug, I have an authorization error.

( You can find below the code of each component and error message)**

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKQyd.png)

---

**PageLogin.xaml.cs**

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class PageLogin : ContentPage
    {
        public PageLogin ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            this.btnLogin.Clicked += BtnLogin_Clicked;
        }

        private void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BOWCF.Classes.WebService service = new BOWCF.Classes.WebService();
            service.Logged += Service_Logged;
            service.Login(this.txtId.Text, this.txtPassword.Text);
        }

        private void Service_Logged(object sender, BOWCF.Models.User e)
        {
            if (e.Enabled)
            {
                Classes.Security.CurrentUser = e;
                Application.Current.MainPage = new Pages.PageMain();
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("TPTFS03", "Connexion Failed", "Ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**BOWCF.Classes.WebService**

```
    public event EventHandler<Models.User> Logged;
    public void Login(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX:XXXX/ServiceTPTFS03.svc");
                SvcTPTFS03.ServiceTPTFS03Client client = new SvcTPTFS03.ServiceTPTFS03Client();

                client.LoginCompleted += Client_LoginCompleted;

                client.LoginAsync(username, password);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logged?.Invoke(null, new Models.User());
            }
        }

    private void Client_LoginCompleted(object sender, SvcTPTFS03.LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Models.User user = Models.User.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                user = new Models.User()
                {
                    Uid = e.Result.Uid,
                    NameLast = e.Result.NameLast,
                    NameFirst = e.Result.NameFirst,
                    Login = e.Result.Login,
                    Password = e.Result.Password,
                    Enabled = e.Result.Enabled
                };
                Logged?.Invoke(null, user);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }  
    }       
}
```

---

**IServiceTPTFS03.CS**

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceTPTFS03
    {
        [OperationContract]
        User Login(string login, string password);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class User
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid Uid { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        [DataMember]
        public string NameLast { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [DataMember]
        public string NameFirst { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [DataMember]
        public string Login { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [DataMember]
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [DataMember]
        public bool Enabled { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

---

**ServiceTPTFS03.svc.cs**

```
public class ServiceTPTFS03 : IServiceTPTFS03
    {
        public User Login(string login, string password)
        {
            User user = new User();
            if (login == "dreau.valerie@swiss-bourdin.com"
                && password == "1234")
            {
                user.Uid = Guid.Parse("AECB05C7-8003-4685-98CD-658761DC7C53");
                user.NameLast = "Dreau";
                user.NameFirst = "Valerie";
                user.Login = "dreau.valerie@swiss-bourdin.com";
                user.Password = "1234";
                user.Enabled = true;              
            }                     
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure your IIS server can accept remote requests?  By default the IIS that comes with VS is limited to local requests

Comment: The IIS i use is on windows server and  i check all fonctionality needed.The WebService work with UWP or in browser with distant IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution.
**1- You must make sure that the android.permission.INTERNET manifest is active.

2- Do not forget to REBUILD the solution.**

Answer (score 0):

In your "BOWCF.Classes.WebService" you must pass the httpbinding and endpointadress.

Try this : new SvcTPTFS03.ServiceTPTFS03Client(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
I explain to you, the "basicHttpBinding" it's a variable and same "endpointAddress", if you don't pass the parameter it's not possible for the external network, because the client initialize with the default parameters.

But it's a Good Job.